# Add column to excel pivot refering to pivot results?

Tags: excel, pivot

I create a Pivot table where some columns are sums of values (e.g. A=sum(a), B=sum(b)). Is there a way to easily add a calculation on these aggregated results? Basically an additional columns next to the Pivot telling me the ratio A/B?

Comment: Have you looked into PivotTable Calculated Fields?

Comment: Not sure I understand them. To me it seemed they operate on the table data (a,b) and not on the pivot aggregated data (A,B)?!

Comment: I think I understand your problem. You might try evaluating the ratio in another column in your source data and then including that in the source of your PivotTable. It's often just a case of using a simple formula in your data and the *average* feature of the PivotTable evaluation

Comment: I'm not sure any table data could reproduce A/B by averaging :/ One could copy the Pivot table to normal cells and work there, but I'd rather refer to the Pivot table directly.

Comment: What i mean is that if you create a column that has a formula like `=SUM(A:A)/SUM(B:B)` and dragged it down. You wouldn't want the PivotTable to sum that column, you'd want an average when including it in your Pivot